# Unicode characters won't print in clojure repl (nor via ring http response)

Tags: tomcat, clojure, jvm

I have the following issue within a clojure repl on an aws ec2 instance (3.2.30-49.59.amzn1.x86_64) running inside of Tomcat 7:

```
user=> (println "Tiësto")
Ti�sto
```

Naturally, I verify that my file encoding is utf-8:

```
user=> (get (System/getProperties) "file.encoding")
"UTF-8"
```

... so far, so good. Maybe its a repl input problem, so I escape the input:

```
user=> (println "Ti\u00ebsto")
Ti�sto
```

... now I try to print it out to a log instead

```
user=> (info "Tiësto")
output from the log:
2013-03-30 19:04:06.569 INFO  default    user - Tiësto
```

Great! although this problem still persists when spitting "Tiësto" out through a ring handler:

```
{
 ...
  artists: ["Ti�sto"],
 ...
}
```

None of these issues occur in my development environment (of course). Anyone have some idea of what might be going on?

Comment: In case you are accessing the REPL with a browser, the browser might get the character encoding wrong.
See document.characterSet in the web/javascript console.
In Google Chrome, use Settings->Tools->Encoding

Comment: It seems to be an environment issue rather than anything related to Clojure or JVM itself. Just check your `locale` on shell, it should yield something sensible like "en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the Content Type and Character Encoding:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");  
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
out.println(Tiësto);
```